# Count values in other tables based on values in source table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I'm sure it's been asked before but I can't find it...
In Excel, can I use a formula to `COUNTIF` or `SUMIF` from other tables based on a value in the first column of the source table?
Example:

```
Index         StepCount     totalPass   totalFail
tblUserLogin    1               13          3
tblPMOUser      1               13          3
tblSAUser       1               13          3
```

The formula in B2 is something like:
`Count the steps in the table named A2`
Thinking that I could build a string to equal the criteria, I tried this: `=COUNTA("[@[Index]]"&"[Step]")` to no avail.

C2 and D2 would be:
`Count the number of PASS/FAIL in column D from the table named A2`

Two outcomes that I hope for:
1) Point me in the right direction formula-wise
2) Tell me that it can't be done without VB

Comment: Use countif for one criteria and countifs for one or more. Select te ranges with your mouse and the correct table name/column name will be filled in.

Comment: @Jeeped - I get that part...what I am missing is: how do I tell the COUNTIF statement that the value that I want is in column A of my current table?

Comment: Click the cell with the mouse. You'll get something like @[Index] meaning index column, same row, same table. [Using structured references with Excel tables - Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for your Step you need:

```
=COUNTA(INDIRECT(A2&"[Step]"))
```

Just apply the same for the other functions.

Or if is a table, use:

```
=COUNTA(INDIRECT([Index]&"[Step]"))
```

Comment: Thanks, @zipa - exactly what I needed.